# How do I copy a binary search tree in pre-order traversal in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy one BST to another BST in c++ but can't figure out how to do it in pre-order traversal. I have attached an image below of what I have tried with no success. I just keep getting segmentation faults thrown. I must do It with the two functions I have show. The first one is in public which calls out to the void copy that is in private.

```
BST::BST(const BST &obj):root{nullptr}
{
    copy(obj.root);
}

void BST::copy(const TNodePtr Tree)
{
     TNodePtr tempTree = new (nothrow) TNode;
    tempTree = nullptr;
    if (Tree == nullptr){
        cout << "No elements in tree. " << endl;
    }else if(Tree->left != NULL)
    {
        tempTree->element = Tree->element;
        copy(Tree->left);
        copy(Tree->right);
    }
    delete tempTree;
}
```

Below is the provided .H file that can't be altered what-so-ever.

```
#pragma once // alternative Guard format
#include <string>

typedef std::string TElement;
struct TNode;
typedef TNode * TNodePtr;
struct TNode {
        TElement element;
        TNodePtr left, right;
};


class BST {
        public: // exportable
                // General description of each of the ADT operations/functions – exportable operations only
                BST();
                BST( const BST & );
                ~BST();
                void insert( const TElement );
                void remove( const TElement );
                TNodePtr search( const TElement ) const;
                void preView() const;
                void inView() const;
                void postView() const;
        private: // non-exportable
                // No private member documentation – implementation details are hidden/abstracted away
                TNodePtr root;
                void copy( const TNodePtr );
                void destroy( TNodePtr & );
                void removeNode( TNodePtr & );
                void findMinNode( TNodePtr &, TNodePtr & );
                void insert( const TElement, TNodePtr & );
                void remove( const TElement, TNodePtr & );
                TNodePtr search( const TElement, const TNodePtr ) const;
                void preView( const TNodePtr ) const;
                void inView( const TNodePtr ) const;
                void postView( const TNodePtr ) const;
};
```

Comment: Please don't copy code as image; type it here.

Comment: The thing that is wrong with your code is that `copy` is a `void` function. Since it is making a copy it must return that copy. Change `void BST::copy(const TNodePtr Tree)` to `TNodePtr BST::copy(TNodePtr Tree)` and start from there.

Comment: @john I must do It with the two functions I have show. The first one is in public which calls out to the void copy that is in private.

Comment: @Learning2Code OK, I'll edit my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is that a function which makes a copy has to return that copy. But your `copy` function is `void`. That's why you can't make it work.

Something like this

```
BST::BST(const BST& obj) : root(copy(obj.root))
{
}

TNodePtr BST::copy(TNodePtr Tree)
{
    if (Tree == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        TNodePtr node = new TNode();
        node->element = Tree->element;
        node->left = copy(Tree->left);
        node->right = copy(Tree->right);
        return node;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Apparently the signature of the `copy` function and class generally is non-negotiable. So we'll write another function which does the real work, and call that function from `copy`. Like this

```
static TNodePtr real_copy(TNodePtr Tree);

BST::BST(const BST& obj) : root(nullptr)
{
    copy(obj.root);
}

void BST::copy(const TNodePtr Tree)
{
     root = real_copy(Tree);
}

static TNodePtr real_copy(TNodePtr Tree)
{
    if (Tree == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        TNodePtr node = new TNode();
        node->element = Tree->element;
        node->left = real_copy(Tree->left);
        node->right = real_copy(Tree->right);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Here's we are using an additional function `real_copy` but since that function is not part of your classes and is local to your implementation source file you don't have to edit the header file.

Comment: See that is my issue. I can't add in that extra function. I am strictly limited to the two functions.

Comment: @Learning2Code Why? Makes no sense. Makes the problem 20 times more difficult than it should be. I'm not even certain it is possible. Probably you misunderstood something.

Comment: @Learning2Code Forty years as a professional programmer, and no-one ever said to me, please do this task but you're not allowed to write any extra functions. I can't second guess your teacher, but I think the thing to do would be to ask them why they have placed this restriction on you.

Comment: I went in and added in my .h file that I can't change whatsoever for reference to what I am limited to

Comment: @Learning2Code OK, I'll make another edit. Not be able to edit a header file is not the same thing as not being able to write any additional functions.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work re-using my insert function.

Comment: @Learning2Code OK good, I did briefly see your implementation, but now it's gone, so I can't comment.